# Triggering Widget Rebuilds with Provider's context.read<T>() Method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

According to Flutter's documentation and [this example](https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/provider_counter/lib/main.dart), as I'm understanding it, a key difference between the Provider package's `context.read<T>` and `context.watch<T>` methods relate to triggering widget rebuilds. You can call `context.watch<T>()` in a `build` method of any widget to access current state, and to ask Flutter to rebuild your widget anytime the state changes. You can't use `context.watch<T>()` outside build methods, because that often leads to subtle bugs. Instead, they say, use `context.read<T>()`, which gets the current state but doesn't ask Flutter for future rebuilds.

I tried making this simple app:

```
class MyDataNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _testString = 'test';

  // getter
  String get testString => _testString;

  // update
  void updateString(String aString) {
    _testString = aString;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => MyDataNotifier(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(context.read<MyDataNotifier>().testString),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Level1(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Level1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          onChanged: (val) {
            context.read<MyDataNotifier>().updateString(val);
          },
        ),
        Text(context.read<MyDataNotifier>().testString),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

All the calls are to `counter.read<T>()`. The app's state changes, but the UI is not rebuilt with the new value. I have to change one of the calls to `counter.watch<T>()` to get the state to rebuild.

On the other hand, in [DZone's simple example](https://dzone.com/articles/flutter-20-state-management-introduction-with-prov), the UI rebuilds, and all the calls are to context.read().

What's different between their code and mine? Why can't I rebuild with counter.read() calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: after a quick glance, the DZone article looks like it has a bug.

### Longer answer

`context.watch<Foo>()` does 2 things:

1. return the instance of the state from the tree
2. mark `context` as dependent on `Foo`

`context.read<Foo>()` only does 1).

Whenever your UI depends on `Foo`, you should use `context.watch`, since this appropriately informs Flutter about that dependency, and it will be rebuilt properly.

In general, it boils down to this rule of thumb:

- Use `context.watch` in `build()` methods, or any other method that returns a `Widget`
- Use `context.read` in `onPressed` handlers (and other related functions)

The main reason people seem to use `context.read` inappropriately is for performance reasons. In general, preferring `context.read` over `context.watch` for performance is an *anti-pattern*. Instead, you should use `context.select` if you want to limit how often a widget rebuilds. This is most useful whenever you have a value that changes often.

Imagine you have the following state:

```dart
class FooState extends ChangeNotifier {
  // imagine this us updated very often
  int millisecondsSinceLastTap;

  // updated less often
  bool someOtherProperty = false;
}
```

If you had a widget that displays `someOtherProperty`, `context.watch` could cause many unnecessary rebuilds. Instead, you can use `context.select` only depend on a processed part of the state:

```dart
// read the property, rebuild only when someOtherProperty changes
final property = context.select((FooState foo) => foo.someOtherProperty);  
return Text('someOtherProperty: $property');
```

Even with a frequently updating value, if the output of the function provided to select doesn't change, the widget won't rebuild:

```dart
// even though millisecondsSinceLastTap may be updating often,
// this will only rebuild when millisecondsSinceLastTap > 1000 changes
final value = context.select((FooState state) => state.millisecondsSinceLastTap > 1000);
return Text('${value ? "more" : "less"} than 1 second...');
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you!